# Change JTextField enabled background color

Tags: java, swing, colors, background, jtextfield

i've got a question about `JTextField` background color. How can I change it in enabled text field (while editing) ? `setBackground` works only for disabled text field. `UIManager.put` can change this background for all of my text field in window but i want to do that only for one of them.

Comment: Do you want to change the background color or the text color of the currently focused field?

Comment: Backgorund color. So .setForeground doesn't work.

Comment: UIManager.put has two - three keys for focus in JTextField

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there is what i needed:

```
Properties props = new Properties(); props.put("showFocusFrame", "off");     
((AbstractLookAndFeel)UIManager.getLookAndFeel()).getTheme().setProperties(prop‌​s);
```

Answer (score 12):

There's a number of ways you might achieve this, but the basic idea is, when the field gets focus, you want to set the fields background color to something else and when it loses focus, you want to reset it...

[image: FocusChange]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class FocusedField {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FocusedField();
    }

    public FocusedField() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JTextField field1 = new JTextField(20);
                JTextField field2 = new JTextField(20);

                FocusListener highlighter = new FocusListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                        e.getComponent().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                        e.getComponent().setBackground(UIManager.getColor("TextField.background"));
                    }
                };

                field1.addFocusListener(highlighter);
                field2.addFocusListener(highlighter);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
                gbc.gridwidth = gbc.REMAINDER;
                frame.add(field1, gbc);
                frame.add(field2, gbc);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I would be tempted to write a simple singleton "manager" which allowed you to register and unregister fields as you needed.

You might also be able to achieve something similar by attaching a `PropertyChangeListener` to the `KeyboardFocusManager`, this would allow you to basic apply this highlighting concept to all fields within in any program without the need to change any of the code, but that would depend on your requirements

Comment: Ok thanks for all responses but now i discover the reason of my problem. In my program i use jtatoo look & feel, and it in some way overwrite my background color of editing textfield. How can i remove it?

Comment: You're best bet is to ask the author

Comment: Ok, there is what i needed:
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("showFocusFrame", "off");       ((AbstractLookAndFeel)UIManager.getLookAndFeel()).getTheme().setProperties(props);

Answer (score 0):

Just add an ActionListener on your textField, and then set the Background in the Listener.

Comment: I don't have a problem with recognize which text field is focused but with change its backgorund. textField.setBackground changes it, but when you click on that field to edit background changes to default one again.

Answer (score -1):

I think it works with `textField.setForeground(Color.RED)` :)

Comment: Sets the text color of the field