# JTextField - how to set background color?

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtextfield

I want to know how to set color of my `JTextField` component. I tried this way:

```
setBackground(Color.white)
```

and it sets a white color, but when the field is marked. I want the field to be white immediately after my program starts and without any user interaction.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change background color by this code

```
textField.setBackground(Color.RED);
```

You should also check this [Change JTextField enabled background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880068/change-jtextfield-enabled-background-color)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot replicate the problem you're having. Perhaps you are initially seeing the background color of the component holding the JTextField, rather than the JTextField's background.

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
f.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));

JTextField tf = new JTextField();
tf.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
f.add(tf);

f.setSize(500, 500);
f.setVisible(true);

Thread.sleep(2500);
tf.setBackground(Color.RED);
```