# Customizing JTextField in Synth

Tags: java, look-and-feel, synth

I need to change the text color in a JTextField when it gets focus, but it looks like just the state SELECTED works.

```
<style id="textfield">
  <state value="SELECTED">
        <color value="#87A0DC" type="TEXT_BACKGROUND"/>
        <color value="#000000" type="TEXT_FOREGROUND"/>
  </state>

  <state value="FOCUSED">
      <color value="#000000" type="TEXT_BACKGROUND"/>
      <color value="#87A0DC" type="TEXT_FOREGROUND"/>
  </state>
</style>
```

I already have tried with BACKGROUND and FOREGROUND either, but nothing has changed.

If anyone can help, Please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change JTextField enabled background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880068/change-jtextfield-enabled-background-color)

Comment: It resolves, but I want do this using the synth library.